# How to modify value of Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of Object:

```
function focal( name, data )
{
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
}

count = 0;
arrayFocal = [];
arrayFocal[ count ] = new focal( "James", "12/08/2014" );
count++;
```

Now I want to modify same values, like this:

```
arrayFocal[ 0 ].name = "Jhon";
```

or

```
arrayFocal[ 0 ][ 'name' ] = "Jhon";
```

But it returns an error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined*
Can sameone help me?

Comment: so how do it set the value of the elements in this case?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsbin.com/wacipena/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no object in the array at the certain position, you need to create it first, i.e.:

```
arrayFocal[2] = {name: 'John', data: 'something'};
```

EDIT:

here's JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q4V6w/1/

Answer (score 2):

Because your array have two elements but your max index is 1. If you want to access to the second element `use arrayFocal[ 1 ] not arrayFocal[ 2 ]`

Remember, array index begins from 0.

Comment: this is just an exemple... my array has more than 100 elements

Comment: Then you need to check what do you have in arrayFocal[ 2 ]. You can use console.log(arrayFocal[ 2 ]) and see it on broswer console. Becuase it seems you have nothing in arrayFocal[ 2 ].

Comment: @Thiago Well, you should show us more code then (edit your question and insert a better example of how you are actually looping to fill the array).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access an index that doesn't exist `arrayFocal[ 2 ].name = "New Name";`

Try to access the index **0** to do this operation, or use an **counter** to do it better.

```js
arrayFocal[0].name = "New Name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
function focal( name, data )
{
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
}

count = 0;
arrayFocal; // considering this is the array you want to modify

for (i=0; i < arrayFocal.length; i++) { // iterates the current array and replace the values with the properties
    arrayFocal[i] = new focal( "James", "12/08/2014" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are all indexed from 0 so in order to access what looks to be from your question the only element in your array, you would need to call `arrayFocal[0]`

To accomplish what you want, you can do

```
arrayFocal[0].name = "Jhon";
```

It is telling you that what you are accessing is undefined because there is literally no element in the array at the index that you are calling.